# How to create dynamic RDLC data table

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

[image][image][image]I need to pass to RDLC (SQL Server Reporting Services) report a data table with only one known column and all other columns are created at run time. That is I have column A that is know at design time, but before loading the report i will read values from the database and set these values as columns, may be i have one column and may be much more.

I tried this :

dsStatementOfAccount.DtEndDayDataTable dtMat = new dsStatementOfAccount.DtEndDayDataTable();

```
        dtMat.Columns.Add("c1");
        dtMat.Columns.Add("c2");

        DataRow row1 = dtMat.NewRow ();
        row1["Name"] = "Value for column name in row 1";
        row1["c1"] = "a";
        row1["c2"] = "a121"[1]

        dtMat.Rows.Add(row1);

        DataRow row2 = dtMat.NewRow();
        row2["Name"] = "Value for column name in row 2";
        row2["c1"] = "bbb";
        row2["c2"] = "bbb";

        dtMat.Rows.Add(row2);
```

But the report was loaded as the attached image ..
How it can be done ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your data source for the report? Data tables or business objects?

Comment: Is there an attribute you can use to determine column groupings? Can you provide the definition of your data table, please?

Comment: The only column I have now in the table is the "NAME" column.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by creating a column group that is grouped by your "NAME" column.

After adding your table to your report, define all static columns. Then, right-click on the cell where you want the dynamic columns to start at and select "Add Group > Parent Group (Under the column group section)" and choose to Group By "NAME". This should produce the desired effect.

EDIT: Attached picture of what it would look like in VS.
[image: Demonstration of column grouping.]

Comment: It looks like you use ROW groups instead of COLUMN groups based on your picture. Can you post a picture of the non-rendered report in VS?

Comment: check in the question please

Comment: Yes, you are indeed grouping on Rows. I've edited my answer to show what column grouping should look like.